# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" cant parse Date

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a String to a date but it shows that the String is empty, although System.out.println gives back "09-11-0013" a line before

```
XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
String value = (String) d.readObject();
value = value.replace("[", "");
value = value.replace("]", "");
String[] splitted = value.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    String[] finallysplitted = splitted[i].split(" ");
    finallysplitted[1] = finallysplitted[1].replace(":", "");
    addmemo(new Memo(sdf.parse(finallysplitted[0]) , Category.valueOf(finallysplitted[1]), finallysplitted[2]));
}
```

Expected output is a Date but instead it gives me an error

Comment: Do you have a leading whitespace character in front of your date string?

Comment: Can you show us where exactly are you using `System.out.println` in your code?

Comment: Where are you parsing string to date? There is nothing like this in your code. Please always add the exception and stacktrace, when asking questions about errors.

Comment: Has nothing to do with JavaFX or fxml; Removed those tags. (Even if you run this code from the event handler method in a controller of an fxml file, the issue wouldn't be related to JavaFX)

Comment: I would use somthing like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iWreKR/1) instead. You can loop on a `Matcher` to get every block matching and extract the groups. I can provide the code but you need to define the pattern for each line to be complet.

Comment: "09-11-0013" is in finallysplitted[0], so I guess there is something wrong with `sdf.parse(finallysplitted[0]`

Comment: Did you tried with `sdf.parse("09-11-0013")` because it should work.

Comment: yeah sdf.parse("09-11-0013") did actually work, but why?

Comment: The exception you have tell you the value is empty. I would sugess you to trim `splitted[i]` before the split, There is probably a space after a  coma that break your code. `finallysplitted` end up with 4 columns, the first being empty. This would be easy to explained with a [mcve] instead of assuming based on what could go wrong.

Comment: Yeah trimming worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “” cant parse Date
```

Let me assume your split doesn't return what you expect. Since you split using a space, have a space after a comma would explain the problem.

You can check simply by printing the array you create.

To solve it, simply trim the value before splitting it : `splitted[i].trim().split(" ");`.